QFT and double slit experiment - what is interfering with itself?
To my understanding, in QM particles can interfere with themselves because we imagine the state of a system not as specified by the particles position and momentum (like classical mechanics), but instead as specified by the wavefunction which depends on all the positions the particle could have, $\Psi(x)$. For the single-particle case at least, the wavefunction looks like a field, and a field can wave, and waves can interfere with themselves. Thus, we get an interference pattern like we see when we do the double-slit experiment.
In QFT, we instead say that particles are excitations (waves?) of quantum fields, $\phi(x,t)$, and the wavefunction becomes a functional of field configurations, $\Psi[\phi(x,t)]$. Now I am thinking that since the particles are kind-of waves, wavefunction or no, do they interfere with themselves? Or is the pattern in the double-slit experiment still (and only?) caused by the wavefunction? If the latter, is there any way to intuitively see/understand how this happens? Its very hard to imagine waves in $\Psi[\phi(x,t)]$ propagating and interfering with themselves.

One way to look at quantum field theory is that it is the theory of an indefinite number of identical particles.
Before explaining that, let's recall that there are two common bases we can think about in quantum field theory. We will assume we are working with a free theory of a real scalar field, for simplicity.
First, we can work in terms of field eigenstates $|\phi(x)\rangle$, where the field operator $\hat{\phi}(x)$ takes on a definite value
$$
\hat{\phi}(x) |\phi(x) = \phi(x) |\phi(x)\rangle
$$
The wave functional you've defined is expressed in this basis
$$
\Psi[\phi(x,t)] = \langle \phi(x,t) | \Psi \rangle
$$
Second, we can work in terms of a Fock space basis, or space of states with a definite number of particles. For a scalar field, the basis states are:

Vacuum: $| 0 \rangle$
Single particle states: $|p\rangle$
Two particle states: $|p_1\rangle | p_2 \rangle = |p_1, p_2\rangle$
etc

In Fock space, it is easy to define the action of creation and annihilation operators $\hat{a}_p^\dagger, \hat{a}_p$, so for example,
$$
\hat{a}_{p_1}^\dagger \hat{a}_{p_2}^\dagger \cdots \hat{a}_{p_n}^\dagger | 0 \rangle = |p_1 p_2 \cdots p_n \rangle
$$
We can also define a number operator $\hat{N}$ to measure the number of particles in each state
$$
\hat{N} = \int \frac{d^3 p}{(2\pi)^3} \hat{a}_p^\dagger \hat{a}_p
$$
where
$$
\hat{N} |p_1 p_2 \cdots p_n \rangle = n |p_1 p_2 \cdots p_n \rangle
$$
In this framework, the statement that QFT describes an indefinite number of identical particles is the most clear; a general state will not be an eigenstate of $\hat{N}$, and will involve a superposition of states from different sectors of Fock space, with different numbers of particles.
Now, we can express the field operator in terms of the creation and annihilation operators
$$
\hat{\phi}(x) = \int\frac{d^3 p}{(2\pi)^3}\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\omega_p}}\left[\hat{a}_p e^{i p x} + \hat{a}_p^\dagger e^{- i px}\right]
$$
Using this expression, we can derive the fact that the field and number operator do not commute
$$
[\hat{\phi}(x), \hat{N}] \neq 0
$$
Therefore, we cannot simultaneously diagonalize the field and number operators. In other words, if we work on a field basis, then there is not a definite particle number. Or, in general, we should expect a field state $|\phi(x)\rangle$ to be a superposition over all sectors of Fock space
$$
|\phi(x) \rangle = c_0 |0\rangle + \int \frac{d^3 p}{(2\pi)^3} c_p |p\rangle +  \int \frac{d^3 {p_1}}{(2\pi)^3} \int \frac{d^3 {p_2}}{(2\pi)^3} c_{p_1, p_2} |p_1, p_2\rangle + \cdots
$$
where the $c_k$ are c-numbers representing coefficients in a superposition of states. (You can work these out explicitly for a free theory, there's an expression on wikipedia, albeit in different notation).
The upshot of the above is that it's going to be difficult to use the wave functional (as a function of $\phi(x,t)$) to talk about states with definite numbers of particles.
Now, let's go back to the double-slit experiment.
Since we are dealing with a bosonic field theory, there are multiple versions of this experiment we can describe.

The classical version of the double slit experiment is to send a classical wave through the slits and see an interference pattern. This can be described easily using field eigenstates $|\phi(x)\rangle$. We simply start with a classical plane wave state and evolve it, and we will see normal, classical interference effects. One way to view what's going on quantum mechanically is that because we are working with a bosonic field, we can put many particles into the same state. Many particles acting in a similar way will behave like a classical field. The formal version of that is what we saw above, that a field eigenstate will involve a superposition over states with arbitrarily large numbers of particles. This is a boring case.

The quantum version of the double slit experiment is to send a single particle through the slits at one time. We then repeat this experiment many times and build up the superposition.


Now, since we're working with a free theory, you expect "many particles sent one after another" to behave the same way as "many particles sent at once" since the particles don't interact with each other. So from our fancy field theory perspective, we can see how the quantum version will have to give the same result as the classical version if we use many particles.
But if you want to directly see what's going on in the quantum case, one particle at a time, then what all of this is saying is that the wave functional is the wrong tool to understand this physical situation. The wave function makes it easy to understand field eigenstates or states that are approximately field eigenstates. But field eigenstates are going to involve a superposition including states with large numbers of particles, which are precisely what we don't want to deal with to understand the quantum double-slit experiment. The easier way to approach this problem is to restrict ourselves to the single-particle subspace of the full Fock space and ask what happens there. Then, we essentially reduce ourselves to the case of single-particle quantum mechanics (see, eg, Tong's QFT notes, Section 2.8.1).
If you are really determined, you can describe single particle states using a wave function, at least in a free theory. (Here, I'm following wikipedia). You start with the ground state wave functional
$$
\Psi_0[\phi] = \langle 0 | \Psi \rangle = {\rm det}^{1/4} \left(\frac{K}{\pi}\right) \exp\left(-\frac{1}{2} \int d^3 x \int d^3 y \phi(x) K(x,y) \phi(y) \right)
$$
where the covariance $K$ is
$$
K(x,y) = \int\frac{d^3 k}{(2\pi)^3} \omega_k e^{i k(x-y)}
$$
Then, you can define a wave functional for a one-particle state as
$$
\Psi_1[\phi] = \langle p | \Psi\rangle = \left(\frac{2\omega_{p}}{(2\pi)^3}\right)^{1/2} \int d^3 y e^{- i p y} \phi(y) \Psi_0[\phi]
$$
From here, what you would do is (1) construct an appropriate superposition $\Phi$ of one particle states to mimic the set up of the double slit experiment, (2) compute what that superposition is explicitly in terms of $\Psi_1$, (3) compute how to express the operator corresponding to the particle's detected position on the screen $\hat{X}$ in terms of the field operator (to make things fun note there is no exact notion of a position operator in relativistic quantum field theory), (4) compute the expectation value $\langle \Phi | \hat{X} | \Phi \rangle$ as a functional integral
$$
\langle \hat{X} \rangle = \int D \phi_1 \int D\phi_2 \Phi[\phi_1]^\star \hat{X} \Phi[\phi_2]
$$
This is the mess you would need to go through to use the Schrodinger function to understand the double-slit experiment, which is why I would advocate not to use this tool for this problem. Somehow, amazingly, it must give the same answer as you would get using one-particle Fock space states -- I imagine the calculation involves many, many integrals collapsing into delta functions that cancel other integrals -- but I think the only point of doing this calculation would be a macho desire to prove it could be done, rather than deriving any insight about the physics. Unfortunately, this is a common situation in quantum field theory -- there are many ways that in principle should give the same result, but in practice only some methods are useful, and often you need to use different methods for different problems.

Are these field eigenstates valid states for physical particles? For example, are they normalized?

@flippiefanus Field eigenstates are a basis of states, as good as any other basis. So you could describe, eg, scattering processes in terms of this basis. But as I've tried to describe in my answer, that's probably a bad idea. They are better suited for things like describing a background field configuration. In terms of normalization, you could define something akin to a delta function normalization, but it would be a delta functional normalization, like $\langle \phi_1(x) | \phi_2(x) \rangle = \delta[\phi_1(x) - \phi_2(x)]$, where the delta functional is defined wrt a functional integral.

I should also clarify I'm working at physicist level of rigor. I assume if you try to make this 100% mathematically rigorous you run into some kind of issue since the whole Schrodinger functional formalism uses functional integration / path integrals, which as far as I understand aren't defined rigorously.

In your answer is there self interference ... or just the fact that a single particle can occupy a certain state is the "interference"?

@PhysicsDave In the quantum version of the double slit experiment, the interference comes from cancellations in the wavefunction of a single particle (if you like, you could say the wavefunction of a single particle is interfering with itself, although I don't like that language). That's very clear if you work with a single particle wavefunction. It's less clear in field theory, except I try to show conceptually how you can extract a single particle wavefunction from field theory in the situation where that's a good description of the physics (like in the quantum double slit experiment).

There's kind of a problem in that field theory is so powerful and general that it can describe an enormous number of different processes involving arbitrarily large numbers of particles. The quantum double slit experiment is kind of a trivial, single particle process (even though it's fascinating conceptually). Field theory has to be able to describe it, since it can describe basically everything, but extracting that prediction from field theory is not trivial because you have to understand how all of the "extra baggage" you don't need for the double slit experiment cancels out.

Thx  ... I've seen Feynman's path integral used to solve the DSE; it calculates many path lengths from source to a screen point, and based on phase summed and squared it gets a probability to that point.  It turns out light appears to like to travel full wavelengths .... Not sure if that is QFT like or not....

@PhysicsDave Yep! That is a cool way to do it. That path integral is still a path integral for a single particle. You can think of it as a kind of "0+1 dimensional field theory" -- meaning that the particle's position, $q(t)$, is like a field that lives in zero spatial dimensions and one time dimension (ie, $q$ is a function of time). In a way what my answer is saying is that rather than work with a full $3+1$ dimensional field theory path integral, you want to reduce it to the $0+1$ dimensional case to do the double slit experiment.

@Andrew Thank you for the great answer. Is it right to say that in any situation where I try and think of the particle in the DSE not as a particle, but as a field excitation that potentially is smeared out, I am moving away from the actual DSE setup. And that in the actual DSE 'limit', the excitation is so single-particle-like that the proper tool really is QM and not QFT? Hope I am making sense.

@Depenau Yes, that's basically what I would say. Also, QM is embedded in QFT, so in some sense treating the single particle double slit experiment with single particle QM is also treating it with QFT, but you just have to understand how to get the single particle QM limit out of QFT.

In general for the photon the famous Dirac statement "interfere with themselves" is a result of the ability of photons in the DSE to take only certain probable paths. There are no paths to the dark areas, all photons go to the bright bands. Feynman's path integral shows that photons prefer paths of certain path lengths, the lengths being multiples of the wavelength.  Instead of thinking about the photon it may be wiser to think about the EM field, it is known that an excited atom/electron can stay in this excited state for a period of time, all the while interacting with the EM field.
If we shift the understanding from the particle or photon to the universal EM field then yes the particles are interfering with themselves ... but it is more accurate to say the particles are interacting with the EM field ... which gives the wavelike properties.
